# Using Webpack and JS modules, but still getting access to global vars from HTML file

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-modules

I'm new to Webpack and I think I'm missing something.

I've got a simple Javascript file (items.js) which requires some external modules (some from npm, some written by myself). Note: the app is a multi-page application, so Webpack is configured to build from multi entry points, and it will build 1 "common" bundle and 1 "entry point" bundle (so i'm using [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/))

```
var $ =         require("jquery");

var vm = {
    loadData: function() {
        $('#items').text('Data loaded');
    },
    add: function() {
        $('#modal').show();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    vm.loadData();
});
```

Now, in the HTML file, which is

```
<div id="items">Loading...</div>

<button onclick="vm.add()">Add</button>

<form id="modal" style="display: none">
    <input type="text" name="name">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/items.js"></script>
```

I see that Webpack made me lose the visibility to "vm" var, which is not global. But I would like to have access to "vm" var from HTML file, for example to call vm.add() when the user click on "Add" button.

Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Is it visible as `window.vm`?

Comment: Try with `window.nameofvar`.

Comment: Mmm no, it's still undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your webpack.config file, you can expose your top-level variable

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    //you can expose the variable to window
    libraryTarget: 'window',
    library: 'vm'
  }
};
```

Here is a good example that might help you
[expose bundle in a variable in the global context](https://gist.github.com/dreyescat/c3fd66ea0f7e97ba5c21)

[output.library documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library)

Comment: That's the right answer to my question, even though it's not a good practice for my project, because I would end up with dozens of exposed top-level variables, and because I should edit my webpack.config every time I add an entry point to my app.. not very scalable. I think I will face it cleaning up my HTML file, leaving no JS code at all in it. Then, in the JS file (the vm), I'll do something like $('#btn').click(vm.add). So I don't need any global variable any more.

Comment: You can just expose vm as your global entry point, and expose any event handler by association to vm object, but the I idea to use webpack is to avoid naming collision. register event in js is good, you can have a module to handle the event registration, so you don't need have event registration everywhere in your code